# Sequelizejs error to run function on columns - check_ungrouped_columns_walker in

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I want to run a function in the attribute and get different between `startDate` and `endDate`. But when I execute the code get this error:

> column "Signals.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or
>   be used in an aggregate function

```
const lastData = await psql.Signals.findAll({
    attributes: [
     "id",
     "strategy",
     "type",
     "symbol",
     "name",
     "timeframe",
     "status",
     "startDate",
     "endDate",
     [
      Sequelize.literal('EXTRACT(DAY FROM MAX("startDate")-MIN("endDate"))'),
      "DateDifference"
     ],
     "positionsData"
    ],
    where: {
     isMain: true,
     strategy: {
      [Op.in]: ["21", "22"]
     }
    },
    order: [["id", "DESC"]],
    limit: 50,
    raw: true
   })
```

The expected SQL code by Sequelizejs is:

```
SELECT "id", "strategy", "type", "symbol", "name", "timeframe", "status", "startDate", "endDate", EXTRACT(DAY FROM MAX("startDate")-MIN("endDate")) AS "DateDifference", "positionsData" FROM "signals" AS "Signals" WHERE "Signals"."isMain" = true AND "Signals"."strategy" IN ('21', '22') ORDER BY "Signals"."id" DESC LIMIT 50;
```

Can anybody help me? What is wrong?!

Answer (score 0):

Summary functions (MIN, MAX, SUM, etc) usually require a GROUP BY clause.  For what set of data should the MIN and MAX date fields be applied?  Will there be multiple dates per id?